# Postfix crashing on start-up. Why?

Tags: postfix, mail-forwarding

I'm using Debian 6, Postfix 2.9.6 and I want to avoid using MySQL for this, if possible. Here is the appropriate part from `main.cf`

```
virtual_alias_domains = example1.com example2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/etc/postfix/virtual is as follows:

```
example@example1.com example@example3.com
@example2.com example@example3.com
```

If I remove the second line, there is no problem but the desired functionality is gone. If it's there, postfix silently crashes as soon as it starts up. Using `example@example1.com,@example2.com example@example3.com` has the same result. Here's what I mean:

```
# postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
# postfix status
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is not running
# /etc/init.d/postfix start
[ ok ] Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent: postfix.
# /etc/init.d/postfix status
[ ok ] postfix is not running.
```

Last error in /var/log/mail.log is from July 4th so that's not helpful either.

Is this even possible without MySQL?

**EDIT:** `strace postfix start` prints out the text in [this paste](http://pastebin.com/eA8EvT7d)

**EDIT 2:** `postfix check`, `sh -x postfix start` and `strace -f postfix start` results are [here](http://resources.3ventic.eu/putty.log)

Comment: Of course you can do it without mysql, but I've never ever known postfix to crash silently..

Comment: try to run with debug enabled. You can get more info at http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html

Comment: @ALex_hha `strace postfix start` gives me a big bunch of text. I'll update that to the OP once I get my putty logs.

Comment: What about /etc/init.d/postfix check and sh -x /etc/init.d/postfix start? Also would be interesting to see output of the postconf -n. One more thing, could you repost output of the strace, but now add -f flag

Comment: @ALex_hha check returns nothing at all. I'll add the others to the OP in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see from the last output

```
bind(11, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(25), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = -1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
```

It seems that some process already have been listening port 25. You can check it with

```
# netstat -lanp | grep 25
# lsof -i tcp:25
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sendmail is running but.. apt-get removed it before installing postfix (?)

Comment: Yes, uninstall sendmail. http://serverfault.com/questions/524498/postfix-wont-start-says-bind-0-0-0-0-port-25-address-already-in-use-what-sho/524530#524530